# Postgres SELECT WHERE IN array in Java

Tags: java, database, postgresql, where-clause, where-in

I want to select all records form database using WHERE IN, using values form an array that I have. Is there a way to actually pass the array to the query? 
I tried `SELECT id FROM tag WHERE name IN "+myArray.toString()+"`. But, of course, it is destined to fail)
I could use preparedStatement, but number of values is always different and quite large - 5000 or so.
Or maybe I should take a different approach?

Comment: You should always use prepared statements instead of string concatenation for SQL creation. Give MyBatis or Hibernate a look if you want a little more flexibility on what you can use as an input.

Comment: But, I heard that preparedStatement is much slower then string concat. Is it true? (Though, I know preparedStatement is good against sql injections)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use normal concatenation to do this just use a StringBuilder, which is MUCH more efficient since it only actually creates the string when you use the toString() method.

```
private String ArrayToString(String[] array)
{
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    buffer.append(array[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        buffer.append(",");
        buffer.append(array[i]);
    }

    return buffer.toString();
}
```